# How do I parse a csv file?

Tags: ios, csv

I'm trying to implement a label that shows me the current location's weather data as the following:

```
NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=%@&format=csv&num_of_days=0&show_comments=no&key=myKeyThatIRemovedForThisQuestion",city];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:request];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *csv = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
    NSArray *items = [csv componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSLog(csv);
    NSLog([items firstObject]);
    NSLog([items objectAtIndex:1]);
```

The logging line for the csv works.
The logging line for the first object in the array works.

But the objectatindex line throws an unexpected error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

A sample of csv on console:

```
2014-02-27 21:27:43.626  Clock[1470:70b] 08:28 PM,17,116,http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png,Partly Cloudy ,9,15,100,E,0.2,59,16,1012,75
2014-02-27,18,64,8,46,13,22,169,SSE,263,http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0009_light_rain_showers.png,Patchy light drizzle,3.8
```

How can I make this thing work so I can get my data from the array?

Comment: Check CocoaPods for a [CSV Parser](http://cocoapods.org/?q=csv)

Comment: Could you log the full exception error message??

Comment: Most likely you only have one object in `items`. Did you use the debugger and look at the values you get?

Comment: This is the full exception error message. This is my problem: it is usually informative, but this time it is just an "exception".

Comment: You have no line in the debugger before "libc++aby.dylib:terminating..."?

Comment: I'd recommend making a different request and getting a less ambiguous return dataset.  Change the format=csv part to format=json would be one way.

Comment: Also, one should almost always pass at least semi-constant format strings to NSLog (NSLog(@"%@", csv) even if you know the only argument is a string.  If the random data you're passing as the format string happens to have formatting characters in it, random crashes and exceptions can occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Dave Delong's CSV parser a few times without issue.  This can be found here: https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

It is also available via CocoaPods as CHCSVParser.  This library has a test suite - and works fairly efficiently.